Creating a variable with the highest number observed at a family level in Stata
Suppose I have raw data that look like this:



Group
Family
Individual
Highest score




1
4
2
0


1
4
3
1


1
5
1
2


1
6
2
0


1
6
3
2



Here 0 = low, 1 = medium, 2 = high for highest score.
An individual is unique within a family, which is also unique within a group. I want to create a variable that contains highest score for each family - for example, for family no. 4, the new variable of highest score will be 1 for both individual 2 and 3, as it is the highest achieved within family no. 4.
I have tried
egen familyhighscore = max(highestscore), by(family) 

and
bysort family (highestscore): gen familyhighscore = family[_N]

and none of them worked as the way I wanted. How would I create this new "family high score" variable while retaining the same value labels as "highest score"?
I couldn't find an existing post that answers my question yet - apologies if it has been asked before.

If the family is unique only within a group, then the correct command is:
egen familyhighscore = max(highestscore), by(group family) 


This looks right to me. Note that you need to copy any value labels explicitly. The new variable doesn't inherit any value labels.

Hi, thank you so much for your help and @NickCox too - it worked. I just have another question - if we had the extra data for children in each family who are classified according to birth number (also unique within a family), how would I generate a variable that has value label of 1 = if all children received the gift within the family  and 0 = at least one child missed out (e.g. 3 children for family no. 4, but a child with birth number 2 did not receive the gift while the other two did) ?

Please don't ask new questions in comments. Start a new thread with a MRE. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example explains. Otherwise https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/create-variable-recording/ may help.
